# how can i bring imageview above other imageviews by Touch (android)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

its the left circle  [unpressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrg93.jpg)  [pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBOB4.jpg)

so i have imageview = (shaped drawble src), when i touch it change the drawble res to other 
so the color change .but i also want to bring it above other imageviews how can i do that i try bringToFront but is not working, is there another way to do it ??

I want the same for ALL of them when i pressed one imageview its be in front of others.

```
         final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cir);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + event.toString());
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cir_press);
                        break;

                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cir);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="356dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom|center">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cir"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_width="184dp"
            android:layout_height="313dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="63dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="63dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/cir"
            />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cir2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="186dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="211dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="211dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cir2"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cir3"
            android:layout_width="205dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cir2"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-127dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cir3" />


    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="231dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cir4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="212dp"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:src="@drawable/cir4"
            />



    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide xml layout?

Comment: @nik check the xml code

Comment: One of the problems here is the layout is not consistent, the nested RL has match parent, so when you touch somewhere you could be tapping it as well. I recommend you using ConstraitLayout as root and only 1 level nesting. Then try to replace your current heuristic for setting a click listener or touch if you insist, to parent.removeView(view) and then parent.addView(view)

Answer (score 1):

```
imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

OR

---

```
<ImageView         
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/your image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be late for answer but I've noticed that you have given `elevations` in your layout. `imageView.bringToFront()` won't work if you will give your view different `elevations`,also your `@+id/layoutTop` is set to `match_parent` that may cause  `imageView.setOnTouchListener` to stop working so I've adjusted your layout like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="356dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:gravity="bottom|center">


<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cir"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="313dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="63dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="63dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/cir"
/>


<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cir2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="186dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="211dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="211dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cir"
/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cir3"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cir2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-127dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cir"/>


<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="231dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:gravity="bottom">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cir4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="212dp"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:src="@drawable/cir"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also since you've used `RelativeLayout` as topLayout in-order to bring imageView`(cir)` to back of topLayout  you will have to bring `@+id/layoutTop` to front while in unpressed state consider following code:

```
 final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cir);
 final ImageView topLayout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.layoutTop);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + event.toString());
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cir_press);
                    imageView.bringToFront();
                    break;

                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cir);
                    topLayout.bringToFront();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use RelativeLayout as the parent of the imageViews and on each imageView click call `view.bringToFront()`

Comment: but that will make all of them be in front , i only need one when i touch or click be in front of other

Comment: The author is saying `view` as the touched view, not as in the getView method or as in the parent view, give it a try, it sounds logic

Comment: its look like this 


imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view.bringToFront()
            }});